# xyz coordinates manipulation using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a huge number of plain text files containing Cartesian xyz coordinates of chemical structures. A sample could look like that:

```
B                 -1.38372433    0.56274955    2.22204795 
B                  0.01637488    1.69210489    1.81167819
B                  0.29103422   -0.35499374    0.15388510
B                  1.14485163    0.19631678    1.74992009 
Fe                -0.92583118    1.01775624    0.27450973
S                 -0.35374797   -1.05624221    1.74656393
C                 -1.87367299    1.66919492   -1.27526252
O                 -2.42173866    2.04584255   -2.17123145
H                 -2.54747585    0.75818308    2.22742141
H                  0.62677160   -0.81072498   -0.88156036 
H                  0.38495881    2.74424131    2.19841880
H                  2.25808628    0.09159351    1.37282254
```

In this case, each H atom is bonded to a B atom with a distance of 1.18 angstroms. What I'm supposed to do is to change, in turn, each BH vertex by a P vertex. 
Using bash, I'd like to act on all text files at once by taking the coordinates of the first B atom encountered and use it as a point of origin of a sphere and search within a radius of 1.18 Angstroms for the bonded Hydrogen atom, delete this H atom with its coordinates then change the B into a P atom.

An expected output of the above sample would be something like that:

```
P                 -1.38372433    0.56274955    2.22204795 
B                  0.01637488    1.69210489    1.81167819
B                  0.29103422   -0.35499374    0.15388510
B                  1.14485163    0.19631678    1.74992009 
Fe                -0.92583118    1.01775624    0.27450973
S                 -0.35374797   -1.05624221    1.74656393
C                 -1.87367299    1.66919492   -1.27526252
O                 -2.42173866    2.04584255   -2.17123145
H                  0.62677160   -0.81072498   -0.88156036 
H                  0.38495881    2.74424131    2.19841880
H                  2.25808628    0.09159351    1.37282254
```

I've done something similar a while back, but that was adding xyz coordinates of a H atom at a distance of 1.2 Angstroms from an existing B atom. what I used back then was:

```
for i in *.inp; do awk '/^B / { print; if (++count == 1) printf("%-10.8f %-14.8f %-14.8f %s\n", "H", $2+1.2, $3+1.2, $4+1.2); next } { print }' $i > temp/`basename $i`--H.inp; done
```

However, I'm still not successful in coming up with something similar to solve my current problem.

Any help is really appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the expected output for the given input?

Comment: @choroba : Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question to give an expected output of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @P;
my $deleted;
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    $F[0] = 'P', @P = @F if ! @P && 'B' eq $F[0];
    if ('H' eq $F[0] && ! $deleted) {
        die "No B found yet!\n" unless @P;
        my $close = grep abs($F[$_] - $P[$_]) <= 1.18001, 1, 2, 3;
        $deleted = 1, next if 3 == $close;
    }
    print "@F\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Just one inquiry, how about if I want to act on the 2nd B atom or 3rd for example instead of the 1st one encountered?

Comment: @nytrook: Then count the B's until you encounter the one you need.